# Why is Metal is rendering textures SLIGHTLY darker than they should be?

Tags: textures, rendering, metal

I already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47745486/metal-texture-is-darker-than-original-image) question. Using `[MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB : false]` in texture loader options doesn't work. All that happens is when I do `[MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB : true]`, it's a lot darker instead of slightly darker. There must be something else. Here is an example of this unwanted behavior.
[image: Example of unwanted behavior]
As you can see I am using the mouse to hold the original packed ice texture over the rendered one. It's considerably lighter, even with `[MTKTextureLoader.Option.SRGB : false]`.

Here is my fragment function:

```
fragment half4 TextureFragment(VertexOut VertexIn [[stage_in]], texture2d<float> Texture [[texture(0)]]) {
    constexpr sampler ColorSampler(mip_filter::nearest, mag_filter::nearest, min_filter::nearest);
    float4 Color = Texture.sample(ColorSampler, VertexIn.TexCoord.xy / VertexIn.TexCoord.z);
    return half4(Color.r, Color.g, Color.b, 1);
}
```

How can I fix the problem? How can I render the actual texture instead of a darker version?

Note: I must *fix* the problem, not work around it. A workaround would be like `return half4(Color.r, Color.g, Color.b, 1);` from the fragment shader. I must fix the problem from the root.

Comment: If you draw the background white instead of black, do the colors look lighter?

Comment: @PandaPajama I tried a white background, and the texture is still darker